# Running sudo command in post install script from .pkg file (to install a kext)

Tags: macos, kernel-module, kernel-extension, packagemaker

I'm using [Packages](http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/Packages/about.html) to create an installer that places a `.kext` file in `/Library/Extensions`. Then, my post-install.sh file tries to load it as such:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo kextload /Library/Extensions/mykext.kext
```

I tested my installer, but I get a fail at the end:

[image]

However, if I run `kextstat | grep mykext` in terminal, I can see that my kext was actually successfully loaded and placed at its destination path. (I deleted and unloaded the kernel extension beforehand, so I know install is working).

So my questions are: Is there a way to diagnose why the installation failed? Is this just because certificate signing?

Noteworthy:

- I ran this while [System Integrity Protection was disabled](https://www.howtogeek.com/230424/how-to-disable-system-integrity-protection-on-a-mac-and-why-you-shouldnt/) (so I could test my software after manually loading my kernel extension earlier)
- I don't have signed certificates from Apple yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to view the Installer logs via Window > Show Installer Logs.

I believe the issue was that I was pointing to a symbolic link of the kext file, rather than its true path.